# Text content alignment for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got a button (NOT created by xaml) for which I'm setting the content alignment like this:

```
btn.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

but if the content is too long then the text is sliding to the right after a point in which you can't see the text anymore. 
the buttons are created inside panorama item 2 in this grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="Title" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged" FontSize="20">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Wall" Margin="40,0,0,0" Name="PIWall">

        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Messages" Margin="30,0,0,0" Name="PIMail">

        </controls:PanoramaItem>

    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

The button and it's settings are as follows:

```
HyperlinkButton btn = new HyperlinkButton();
        btn.Height = 89;
        btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        btn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        btn.Margin = new Thickness(60, -70, 0, 0);
        btn.Width = 290;
        btn.Content = message;
        btn.FontSize = 22;
        btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        btn.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        panel.Children.Add(btn);
        scrollViewer.Content = panel;
        PIMail.Content = mailscrollViewer;
```

How can i make the text not slide over the grid margins?

Comment: You don't give any detail about the button. How is it created? What is it a child of? What parameters of the button have you set?

Comment: It's unclear whether you want the text to wrap in a new line, trim at the end or simply make a button be as large as the text is?

Comment: @Rich Hopkins I've edited my post with the data.

Comment: @igrali i guess that wrapping the text in a new line would do it

Comment: Ok. You're adding the button to a panel. The panel is the content of a scrollviewer. A different scrollviewer is the content of PIMail (whatever that is).  I don't see where it will be added to your UI.  None of these objects is in your XAML. btn ahs a fixed width, so if text is too long you won't see it...  These are thoughts that come to mind.  There could be more questions when these are filled in.

Comment: Correction: PIMail is in XAML, but the scrollviewer that contains the button btn is not the same scrollviewer that is the content of PIMail.

Comment: @Rich Hopkins check the answer that was given and maybe you could know why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, to wrap text inside a button, you could use XAML like this:

```
<Button Width="200" Height="200">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a long text that fits into button"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

In order to accomplish this in code, you could do the following:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Height = 200;
btn.Width = 300;
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txt.Text = "A huge amount of text that will fill the button";
btn.Content = txt;
ContentPanel.Children.Add(btn);
```

ContentPanel is a simple grid.

EDIT: Modified post for HyperlinkButton

In order to enable text wrapping in hyperlink button you need to edit the style of the hyperlink button. Define it like this in the App.xaml file:

```
    <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The important change is that the TextBlock now contains the TextWrapping property set to "Wrap".

Then use the button like you normally do, just don't forget to set the styling:

```
var btn = new HyperlinkButton();
btn.Height = 200;
btn.Width = 300;
btn.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://bing.com", UriKind.Absolute);
btn.TargetName = "_blank";
btn.Style = Application.Current.Resources["HyperlinkButtonStyle"] as Style;
btn.Content = "This is a huge amount of text that will be in the hyperlink button";
ContentPanel.Children.Add(btn);
```

Comment: that sounds promising but it doesn't work.. When i try it, the button seems empty with no content. only when I'm adding the string directly to the button's content i can see it. I tried it with the code example and not with the xaml since in this case I'm not using the xaml

Comment: what could be the reasons for it not to succeed? does it matter if its a button or an hyperlink button? Do you might know of a different way to do the same thing?

Comment: @YonatanNir I edited the post with details for HyperlinkButton

Comment: in the end i just turned the button into a textblock and just used the double tap event to navigate

Comment: I know this is a 3 years old answer but, the problem may lay in textblock's foreground. Change it into a black or specific color and the problem should be gone.